# How to display many variables in one textView

Tags: java, android

I'm working on my first project in Android Studio and I got stuck in "how to display different variables in one textView". to be more clear I'm working on an app that requires the user to enter the gender. each gender has its own calculation method. so I want to display the result calculation the user do in the main interface and In one TextView. I've tried many times to do it but the result is "0.0"

I added another textView and assigned each calculation method to one textview I was able to display the two results.

```
public class Main_Interface extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private TextView results;
    //private TextView fResults;//this is the second textview that I created.







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__interface);




        results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
        if(results.getText().toString().equals("0.0")) {
            results.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        //fResults = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fResults);
       // if(fResults.getText().toString().equals("0.0")){
        //    fResults.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE );
       // }



        calculateMale();
        calculateFemale();
    }


    public void calculateMale(){
        SharedPreferences s = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        double weight = s.getFloat("weight",0.0f);
        double height = s.getFloat("height",0.0f);
        int age = s.getInt("theDate", 0);


        double results2 = 66+(13.7*weight)+(5*height)-(6.8*age);
        results.setText(""+results2);



    public void calculateFemale(){
        SharedPreferences s1 = getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        double fWeight = s1.getFloat("fWeight",0.0f);
        double fHeight = s1.getFloat("fHeight",0.0f);
        int Fage = s1.getInt("theDate", 0);
        double results3 = 655 + (9.6 * fWeight) + (1.8 * fHeight) - (4.7 *Fage)
                ;
        fResults.setText(""+results3);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = s1.edit();
        editor.putFloat("results", (float) results3);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

displaying the calculation in one textview.

Answer (score 1):

You Are calling these two methods before checking these two methods

calculateMale();
calculateFemale();

```
in onCreate() {

//do this

        calculateMale();
        calculateFemale();

    //Then check the result to make results visible or invisible.

    results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
            if(results.getText().toString().equals("0.0")) {
                results.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make it clear when the function is being called. What actually happening here is you are checking textView's value even before calculating your required values. So it is throwing 0.0.
Simply call calculateMale(); calculateFemale(); before checking textView's value.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing results before calling the two function. Try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main__interface);

        results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);

        calculateMale();
        calculateFemale();

        if(results.getText().toString().equals("0.0")) {
            results.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the result from calculateMale() and calculateFemale() methods:

```
String calculateMale = calculateMale();
String calculateFemale = calculateFemale();
results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
String result = calculateMale.concat(calculateFemale);
if (result.length() >= 0) {
    results.setText(result);
} else {
    results.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```